# Regions of England in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have a list of latitude/longitude which point to some cities in England.
For each of these coordinates I want to get the region they belong to.

By region, I mean one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England

For instance: For coordinates (53.38112, -1.47008), ie. Sheffield, I need to find **Yorkshire and the Humber**.

To achieve this, I tried to use Google Reverse Geocoding API:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.38112,-1.47008&key=

Google then tells me that:

- country is **United Kingdom**
- administrative_area_level_1 is **England**, which is a State (or kind of)
- administrative_area_level_2 is **South Yorkshire**, which is a County
- administrative_area_level_3 is **Sheffield District**, which is a District

So Google returns me the correct State, County and District. However, Region is missing.
Is there any way to obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) I don't think the Google API returns such information.

An alternative way to get round this would be to build a list of which counties belong in which of the 9 regions and then look up the region based on the county name. Obviously, this would be a bit of work on your part putting all the county names into a list.

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid, but I guess I have no other options. For the whole UK, I've found 170 different level_2 places (Counties, Unitary Authorities and so on).

Comment: I've worked with addresses a lot and they can be very frustrating.  According to the Royal Mail postcode search, my address' town is is actually my county name and the county is the administrative region. No logic to it.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't directly answer your query, you could use a [set of polygons which trace the regions](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1d5LmqKYvkTDxmYK3-9-aQLNz3Z0QAEwqHusAm5w) and a [point in polygon algorithm](http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/) (this example is in PHP but the algorithm exists in many languages) which would allow you to check which of the regions any latitude and longitude is in